# Mongo java driver add fields value population from indexOfArray

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
$match : { filterQuery}
},
{
$addFields :{ “customGradeOrder” : { $indexOfArray: [ [“Gold”, “Silver”, “Bronze”] , “$grade” ] }}
},{$sort : { customGradeOrder : 1 } }
]);
```

Does mongo java driver Aggregates has any method to add fields with values resolved from index of array operator ?

Example  ::

Student 1:
Name   grade
A      Silver

Student 2 :
Name grade
B     Gold

Student 3:
Name grade :
C     Bronze

The query is to query the student collection and get it sorted in specific value of grades of students (not in simple ascending or descending order.)

Output would be :
B     Gold
A      Silver
C     Bronze

Comment: Can you elaborate more, with some input and output, what you intend to achieve?

Comment: Query is for sorting a collection based on specific order of possible values of an attribute, which is different from simple ascending or descending sorting. I am struggling to find appropirate methods from java driver to addFileds to aggregate with index of arrays

Comment: Is this playground correct https://mongoplayground.net/p/CoYVHK5pUas? And if it is, are you using native mongodb driver?

Comment: Yes illustrated sample is correct and using mongo legacy driver java(not using spring mongo)

Comment: This seems to be working                                                                              
 List<String> gradeOrderList = new ArrayList<>();
gradeOrderList.add("Gold");
gradeOrderList.add("Silver");
gradeOrderList.add("Bronze");
List<Object> indexExpression = new ArrayList<>();
indexExpression.add(gradeOrderList);
indexExpression.add("$grade");
Aggregates.addFields(new Field("customGradeOrder", new Document("$indexOfArray", indexExpression)));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as well, apart from the solution you mentioned:

```
FindIterable<Document> result = collection.aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$addFields", 
    new Document("customGradeOrder", 
    new Document("$indexOfArray", Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList("Gold", "Silver", "Bronze"), "$grade")))), 
    new Document("$sort", 
    new Document("customGradeOrder", 1L))));
```